# Add colored titlebar in Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, titlebar

Im using node.js and electron to create a desktop app.
I try to change the color of my titlebar with [electron-titlebar-windows packge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-titlebar-windows).

I add to my code that lines:

```
const ElectronTitlebarWindows = require('electron-titlebar-windows');
const titlebar = new ElectronTitlebarWindows();
```

but its trow an error:

```
App threw an error during load
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

How to use this package?

Comment: Generally I can not use a "document".

Comment: Hi, @Neil answered your question, but to add to that, check out photon which is a styling library for electron specifically. You'd have to create a transparent background and remove the window frame on your own but the result is really worth it. You can customize your window to look just the way you want it. Just found about it yesterday and I integrated it into my video annotation app right away.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. The problem is that you are declaring `ElectronTitlebarWindows` & the `titlebar` in the `main` (a.k.a background) process where you need to declare & use them in the `renderer` process. Since the background process will not have the reference to the document, which is the `ReferenceError` that you're seeing.